# Using a lot of IF in loop WHILE to print information

Tags: php, mysql

I made a code and it is doing what I want.

But, I would like to know if I am doing it right or in the best way.

Could you please give me your thoughts about it? Thank you.

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);   
$p_before = "";
$year_before = "";

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $p_now= $rows["cop"];

    if ($rows["year"] < 10) {
        $year = "0" . $rows["year"];
    } else {
        $year = $rows["year"];
    }

    if ($rows["month"] < 10) {
        $month = "0" . $rows["month"];
    } else {
        $month = $rows["month"];
    }
    if ($p_now!== $p_before) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "   " . $p_now. "</br>";
        echo $rows["cdp"] . "</br>";
    }
    if ($year_before !== $rows["year"] && $rows["cf"] == $rows["month"]) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . "FRST" . "<br>";
    }

    if ($rows["cdi"] !== null) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["coi"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdi"] . "<br>";
    }
    if ($rows["cdh"] !== null) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["coh"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdh"] . "<br>";
    }
    if ($rows["cdf"] !== null) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["cof"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdf"] . "<br>";
    }
    if ($year_before !== $rows["year"] && $rows["cs"] == $rows["month"]) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . "SENM" . "<br>";
    }
    if ($year_before !== $rows["year"] && $rows["cl"] == $rows["month"]) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . "LAST" . "<br>";
    }
    $p_before = $rows["cop"];
    $year_before = $rows["year"];
}
```

Comment: you should change the title to express, briefly, what the code is being used for.

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Comment: I think it is really clear what I want to ask.

Comment: @LowRider I wasn't the downvoter, but my guess goes to the fact that your question needs some meat. You currently provide no context and no description of what the code does. As such, we don't know what the code is supposed to do and if it is doing it well.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, and to get better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Extract common logic to functions

Notice the duplicated logic here:

> ```
> if ($rows["year"] < 10) {
>     $year = "0" . $rows["year"];
> } else {
>     $year = $rows["year"];
> }
>
> if ($rows["month"] < 10) {
>     $month = "0" . $rows["month"];
> } else {
>     $month = $rows["month"];
> }
> ```

Extract to a function:

```
function pad($num) {
    return $num < 10 ? "0" . $num : $num;
}
```

And then reuse instead of copy-paste:

```
$year = pad($rows["year"]);
$month = pad($rows["month"]);
```

---

Another example:

> ```
> if ($rows["cdi"] !== null) {
>     echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["coi"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdi"] . "<br>";
> }
> if ($rows["cdh"] !== null) {
>     echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["coh"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdh"] . "<br>";
> }
> if ($rows["cdf"] !== null) {
>     echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows["cof"] . "<br>" . $rows["cdf"] . "<br>";
> }
> ```

Extract common logic:

```
function print_date($year, $month, $key1, $key2) {
    $value1 = $rows[$key1];
    if ($value1 !== null) {
        echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . $rows[$key2] . "<br>" . $value1 . "<br>";
    }
}
```

And then reuse instead of copy-paste:

```
print_date($year, $month, "cdi", "coi");
print_date($year, $month, "cdh", "coh");
print_date($year, $month, "cdf", "cof");
```

Actually,
now that I see that only the "i", "h", "f" are different,
it *might* make sense to go further, improve the helper function to make this easier use work too:

```
print_date($year, $month, "i");
print_date($year, $month, "h");
print_date($year, $month, "f");
```

Or not, maybe that's too much.
How far you go, I leave that up to you.

---

Apply this technique to the rest of the code:
try to reuse logic as much as possible,
by extracting to common functions with appropriate parameters.
Stop copy-pasting code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Thank you. Because your comment it gave me a different idea with classes and functions. Thank you for be a "helper" and not a "hater" who don't help who is learning.

Comment: You could use `str_pad($num, 2, 0,  STR_PAD_LEFT)` instead of that trenary operator. Also, an alternative way to write that `echo` could be `echo "{$year}  {$month}  {$rows[$key2]}<br>{$value1}<br>";`, or to use commas instead to spare string concatenations.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>     if ($rows["year"] < 10) {
>         $year = "0" . $rows["year"];
>     } else {
>         $year = $rows["year"];
>     }
>
>     if ($rows["month"] < 10) {
>         $month = "0" . $rows["month"];
>     } else {
>         $month = $rows["month"];
>     }
> ```

You never use `$year` and `$month` separately, so you can replace this entire section with something like

```
    $year_month = sprintf('%02u  %02u', $rows['year'], $rows['month']);
```

Then you can use `$year_month` wherever your code has `$year . " " . $month`.

I prefer to use single quotes where I can.  It has a slight performance benefit since double quotes have to check for variable interpolation.  The main benefit though is that it is obvious that variable interpolation will not occur if you use the single quotes.

> ```
>         echo $year . "  " . $month . "  " . "FRST" . "<br>";
> ```

Concatenating static strings looks wrong to me.  I suppose it's only a slight performance hit, but it seems an entirely unnecessary one.  You could just say either

```
        echo "$year_month  FRST<br>";
```

or

```
        echo $year_month . '  FRST<br>';
```

Note that the first version will be slightly faster but not enough so to matter.  You also might want to consider

```
        echo "$year_month  FRST<br>\n";
```

It won't matter in a browser, but if you have to read source, it's easier to read with the extra newlines.  Of course if you are going for a minimal source size to keep bandwidth down, that would be another story.

Note that `\n` only works in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but @janos gave me a better approach.

Comment: The fastest version of the `echo` would be using single-quotes and using commas, instead of concatenation. Your echo would look like this: `echo $year_month, '  FRST<br>';`